# How do I update the state of a variable with a wait time using promise inside React functional components?

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise

I have the following code and my goal is to update the value of `text` on the button click after 2 seconds. While the console log is taking 2 seconds to print, the `text` value is being updated right away. How can I make it to wait for 2 seconds to update the `text` value?

```
function App() {
    const [text, setText] = React.useState('Initial state');

    const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Changed state');
            resolve('Changed state');
        , 2000);
    });

    const handleOnClick = () => {
        myPromise
        .then(res => setText(res))
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    };

    return (
        <p>{text}</p>
        <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Click Me!</button>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of the following:

1. Your `App` component initially renders.
2. `mypromise` `Promise` object gets initialized and therefore triggers its timeout.
3. When you press the button, 2000ms have already gone (from the render time) and therefore the `mypromise` has already resolved.
4. Your `then` function is immediately applied and calls `setText`.
5. `setText` forces your component to re-render.
6. So the App function re-runs, and the `mypromise` object re-initializes forcing the setTimeout to re-trigger.

A way to fix it is to make your promise run lazily:

```
  ...
  const myPromise = () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Changed state");
        resolve("Changed state");
      }, 2000);
    });

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    myPromise()
      .then((res) => setText(res))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  };
  ...
```

Comment: As a sidenote, always make sure that your component is still mounted when you perform async operations. In other words, make sure that your `setText` can be applied when `then` is triggered.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I was almost there, but instead of using `myPromise().then(...`, I was using `myPromise.then(...`, which was obviously causing an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("Initial text");

  const awaitPromise = (ms) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  };

  const handleClick = async () => {
    await awaitPromise(2000);
    setText("Something else");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {text}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I was getting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`. I googled it, and it looks like a missing babel plugin might be causing it.

As I am trying to use the Promise to mock an API call, the solution above is more appropriate for me. Thank you for posing your solution though.